# How can I scrape product name and pricing data from an online retailer's webpage using getelementsbyclassname in VBA?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, html, vba

I have written a macro to scrape product information from a retailer's webpage.  It runs fine but does not render any results in my worksheet.  I am having a hard time understanding why.  I enter "sale" into the search inputbox, leading to the following url:

http://www.shopjustice.com/search/?q=sale&originPageName=home

I want the product's name, former price, and current price in my worksheet.  The 
HTML for these elements is as follows:

```
<div class="subCatName">
            <a href="/girls-clothing/colored-jeggings/6611358/651?pageSort=W3sidHlwZSI6InJlbGV2YW5jZSIsInZhbCI6IiJ9XQ==&amp;productOrigin=search%20page&amp;productGridPlacement=1-1" id="anchor2_6611358" class="auxSubmit">Colored Jeggings</a>
        </div>
<div class="cat-list-price subCatPrice">
            <div class="priceContainer">
                <span class="mobile-was-price">
                            was 
                            $26.90</span>
                       <span class="mobile-now-price">
                           now 
                           $10.49</span>
                    </div>

            <div class="price_description">
                        <span class="mobile-extra">
                            Extra 30% off clearance!</span>
                    </div>              
                </div>
```

The code is as follows:

```
Sub test2()

Dim RowCount, erow As Long
Dim sht As Object
Dim ele As IHTMLElement
Dim eles As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set sht = Sheets("JUSTICESALE")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Clothing Item"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "SKU"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Former Price"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Sale Price"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
searchterm = InputBox("ENTER SEARCH TERM")

Application.StatusBar = "LOADING JUSTICE SEARCH"
With ie
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.shopjustice.com/"

Do While .busy Or _
.readystate <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = ie.document

doc.getelementsbyname("q").Item.innertext = searchterm
doc.getElementsByClassName("searchbtn").Item.Click

Application.StatusBar = "EXTRACTING PRODUCT DATA"

Set eles = doc.getElementsByClassName("subCatName")
For Each ele In eles
If ele.className = "subCatName" Then
erow = sht.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1) = doc.getElementsByClassName("auxSubmit")(RowCount).innertext
Cells(erow, 2) = doc.getElementsByClassName("mobile-was-price")(RowCount).innertext
RowCount = RowCount + 1

End If

Next ele

End With

Set ie = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Hi Peter, I appreciate your insight.  It has certainly pre-empted some problems.  However, after adding the below code prior to the edited-to-account-for-missing classname loop, it is still not writing to excel.

```
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
```

What am I missing?

I have also rendered an alternative method for a different retailer's webpage, albeit the same concept, as shown below.  What are your thoughts on this method?  My only issue is a Permission Denied Error 70 at the Select Case line.

```
Sub test5()

Dim erow As Long
Dim ele As Object

Set sht = Sheets("CARTERS")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Clothing Item"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "SKU"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Former Price"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Sale Price"

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.application")

searchterm = InputBox("ENTER CARTER'S SEARCH TERM")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.carters.com/"

Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

.document.getElementsByName("q").Item.innerText = searchterm
.document.getElementsByClassName("btn_search").Item.Click

Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.className

Case “product - name”
RowCount = RowCount + 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innerText

Case “product - standard - price”
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innerText

Case "product-sales-price"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innerText

End Select
Next ele
End With

Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

And once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: You're getting the Permission Denied error because one of the elements in your loop (remember, the `ele` variable is an object of unspecified type in your code) does not have a `.ClassName` property. So you'll still have to account for that type of error handling. It also seems you're wanting to loop through all the elements on the page. Perfectly fine, but remember to detect if an element has children, then you have to loop on those child elements as well. (Don't forget all the additional web pages of items to scrape too.)

Comment: PeterT wrote "but remember to detect if an element has children". Could you please post how to detect if an element has children.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working just fine, with two caveats...

First, after you "click" the search button on the main page, your code is not waiting for the results page to load. Therefore your loop that looks for each item fails because there's nothing there (yet).

Second, you need some error handling when you're parsing the HTML for certain fields to handle the case when those fields are missing. As an example, look at the code here and apply it to your situation:

```vb
For Each ele In eles
    If ele.className = "subCatName" Then
        erow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        On Error Resume Next
        Cells(erow, 1) = doc.getElementsByClassName("auxSubmit")(RowCount).innerText
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Cells(erow, 1) = "ERR: 'auxSubmit' Class Name Not Found!"
            Err.Clear
        Else
        End If
        Cells(erow, 2) = doc.getElementsByClassName("mobile-was-price")(RowCount).innerText
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Cells(erow, 2) = "ERR: 'mobile-was-price' Class Name Not Found!"
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    End If
Next ele
```

Comment: I have made a few edits to the original question above.  Do you have any additional insights you could share?  I appreciate the help.